# A small server with PHP

Tags: php, jsp, web-applications, server

So to clarify everything I haven't got a lot of knowledge in PHP but I know that it is a back-end language.

I want to build a small server (LAN) so that other PC's connected to the router can see a directory that I will have at the server from localhost. And also be able to download any file they want (an optional thing is for them to be able to upload to the server).

So can I do that using PHP? I originally thought of JSP because I have worked with it to build a small site (uni assigment) but I don't know how to do it there either except that I know how to "handle" JSP.

I know that I may start further in front of where I would need to be considering the lack of knowledge in PHP BUT I am prepared to learn everything as long as I can build what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't even need php to do that. Just apache with directory visualization enabled and accepting connection only from the lan.

Comment: Good to know thanks. @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: If you have PHP installed it has a (somewhat simple but probably adequate for the task you describe) built-in web server. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Thank you @Nick very usefull!

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same thing for my client

1)set up one centralize machine where you all the running project and also running xampp server on it.

2)Now access that particular project through IP address of that machine followed by project name.

Note: You can only able to access project followed by IP if you are in LAN